# sum values per id for a specific condition without group by syntax

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to sum the values that have the some id and 'Y'in YN column ,in a case statement, hence I can not use the group by syntax. Please see below an example and my code : Table T

```
ID   Value  YN
1    4      Y
1    6      Y
2    3      N
```

Request:

```
select
case when YN = 'Y'
     then ( select sum(Value) from T group by ID)
     else Value
end as TotalResult;
```

Can you help me displaying only Totalresult ?

Comment: You can absolutely use a `case` expression and a `group by` clause in the same statement; I don't see why you think one precludes the other. I'm also unsure of exactly what you want your result set to look like. Can you please clarify? It's also helpful to mention which RDBMS you're using.

Comment: I am expecting as result :
TotalResult
10
3
Thats all I want to get, if I use group by, then I need to return the ID and the TotalResult. did you get my point? I only need to return the totalresult

Comment: I am using SQL developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you use `GROUP BY` does not mean that you have to include that column in the `SELECT`...

```
SELECT
  SUM(Value)    AS TotalResult
FROM
  T
GROUP BY
  ID, YN

=>

 Total Result
--------------
      10
       3
```

Exactly what query you need, however, is unclear as you have not demonstrated clearly what you want the query to actually do, or what the expected results should be for your sample data.

Comment: i gave just an example, the code i am doing is much more complex, and when i try group by it returns not a group by expression

Comment: Just because your actual code is more complex doesn't stop you making a ***complete*** example to demonstrate the specific complexity you're facing...  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve